# Trendline is not displaying in my chart

Tags: php, fusioncharts, trendline

I am using trendlines for my line chart. But it is not visible in my browser.Can anyone tell me the reason for this. Below i am giving code:

```
<?php
include("Includes/FusionCharts.php");
include("Includes/DBconn.php");
include("Includes/FC_Colors.php");
?>
<html>
    <title> Blood Pressure</title>
    <head>
        <script language="javascript" src="FusionCharts/FusionChart.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <center>
        <?php

        //connect to the DB
        $link= connectToDB();

        $query =  "select * from patient_health order by ondate";

        $result=mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
        //echo $result;
        $strXML = "<graph caption='Blood Pressure Reading' subCaption='Month wise' xaxisname='Current Month' yaxisname='Blood Pressure(Systolic/diastole)'  yAxisMaxValue='400'
    animation='1' rotatenames='1'>";
$categories = "<categories>";
$systolic = "<dataset seriesName='systole'>";
$diaolic = "<dataset seriesName='diastole'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $categories .= "<category name='" . $row["ondate"] . "' />";
    $systolic .= "<set color='AFD8F8' value='" . $row["systole_reading"] . "'  hoverText='systolic' />";
    $diaolic .= "<set value='" . $row["diastole_reading"] . "' color='FEDCBC' hoverText='diastolic'/>";
}
$strXML .= $categories . "</categories>" . $systolic . "</dataset>" . $diaolic . "</dataset>" . "</graph>";
**$strXML .=" <trendlines>
    <line startValue='140' color='91C728' displayValue='Target' showOnTop='1'/>
  </trendlines>";**
//$strXML now has the complete XML required to render the multi-series chart.

//Create the chart - Pie 3D Chart with data from $strXML
   echo renderChartHTML("FusionCharts/FCF_MSLine.swf", "", $strXML, "BloodPressure", 850, 450,false);
   //echo renderChartHTML("FusionCharts/FCF_MSBar2D.swf", "", $strXML, "BloodPressure", 850, 450,false);

       ?>

    </center>

    </body>

</html>
```

Did i place the code correctly or i have to change it . Can anyone please give me solution

Thank you in advance
Ramsai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that in your code, you are closing the `<graph>` tag before adding `<trendlines>`!

Correct code would be:

```
$strXML .= $categories . "</categories>" . $systolic . "</dataset>" . $diaolic . "</dataset>";

$strXML .=" <trendlines>
    <line startValue='140' color='91C728' displayValue='Target' showOnTop='1'/>
  </trendlines>" . "</graph>";
```

Comment: hey thank you very much for your help shamasis, for me colour is not changing for the lines do you know the reason if so please help me

Answer (score 1):

The code for the trend lines should come before you close the graph element, i.e., before 
`</graph>`.

As I've illustrated below:

```
}
**$strXML .=" <trendlines>
    <line startValue='140' color='91C728' displayValue='Target' showOnTop='1'/>
  </trendlines>";**
$strXML .= $categories . "</categories>" . $systolic . "</dataset>" . $diaolic . "</dataset>" . "</graph>";
```

This should show your trend lines.

Comment: Thank you hrisikesh it is working but the colors r not changing for the systolic diastolic. Can you please look into the code and help me please.